# Undefined PDO constants when using pdo_ibm on debian, php7.1 with docker

Tags: php, docker, pdo, db2, debian

I am unable to use the constants PDO::I5_ATTR_DBC_SYS_NAMING and PDO::I5_ATTR_DBC_LIBL when using pdo_ibm.

I am getting the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Undefined class constant
>   'I5_ATTR_DBC_SYS_NAMING' in /www/xxx/xxx/xxx.php:30 Stack trace: #0
>   {main} thrown in /www/xxx/xxx/xxx.php on line 30

My set up is a docker container with Debian 9 and php7.1.
The pdo_ibm.so version 1.3.4 (also tried 1.3.6) is properly installed and enabled with php:
[ibm_pdo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfHGO.png)

My code look like the following:

```
$db = new PDO("ibm:*LOCAL", $user, $password, array(
  PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
  PDO::ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT => true,
  PDO::I5_ATTR_DBC_SYS_NAMING => true,
  PDO::I5_ATTR_DBC_LIBL => "SHZDEV",
));
```

Would anyone have an idea why this error is being thrown? Thank you.

Comment: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=73785

Comment: @mao yes I am connecting to AS400 db2 for i database

Comment: @RiggsFolly the problem is not that the constants are not having the expected effect when used to create the PDO object but that they are not even recognize by php 7.1

Comment: I know, which means 1) they are not in the extension (unlikely) 2) you dont have the extension correctly installed or configured

Comment: @RiggsFolly hmmm what do you mean by incorrectly installed or misconfigured?

Comment: Looks like stackoverflow is not the correct forum for this issue. As @RiggsFolly already referenced the bug for it on bugs.php.net . Maybe ask there again as it appears from the bug commentary that at least one build had those constants defined.

Comment: @mao ok. Thank you both.